# Grouped running total with Power Query M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

This is how my table looks like (1.7 million rows):

[image]

I'm trying to build a running total per customer ID and date.

This is easy to express using DAX, but unfortunately I don't have enough memory on my machine (16GB RAM).

So, I'm trying to find an alternative with Power Query M using buffered tables, etc. but that is too complicated for me.

Can anyone help? Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: After sorting by Date and CustomerID, added index and added a custom column with:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Personalizado", each (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Index]<=i[Index]) [Sales]))
```

I get the following:
[image]

EDIT2:
The whole code:

```
let
    Origem = dataset,
    #"Linhas Agrupadas" = Table.Group(Origem, {"Date", "CustomerID"}, {{"Sales", each List.Sum([Sales]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Linhas Ordenadas" = Table.Sort(#"Linhas Agrupadas",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"CustomerID", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Linhas Ordenadas", each [Sales] <> 0),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Linhas Filtradas", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Personalizado Adicionado" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index","CumSum",(i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Index]<=i[Index]) [Sales]), type number )
in
    #"Personalizado Adicionado"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method1**

Sort your data to start with, perhaps on the date column and CustomerID column. However it appears on screen is the row order it is going to accumulate the total

Add column .. index column...

Add column .. custom column with formula

```
= (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Index]<=i[Index]) [Sales])
```

Right click index column and remove it

Likely adding a Table.Buffer() around the index step will help speed things up

Sample full code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"CustomerID", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.Buffer(Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1)),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index","CumSum",(i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Index]<=i[Index]) [Sales]), type number ),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

**Method 2**:

Create function **fn_cum_total**

```
(Input) =>
let withindex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Input, "Index", 1, 1),
cum = Table.AddColumn(withindex, "Total",each List.Sum(List.Range(withindex[Sales],0,[Index])))[Total]
in cum
```

Create query that uses that function to add cumulative totals to Sales column after grouping on CustomerID

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(Source,{{"CustomerID", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}})),
Running_Total = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows",{"CustomerID"},{{"Data",
    (Input as table) as table =>  let  zz = fn_cum_total(Input),
     result = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Input)&{zz}, Value.Type(Table.AddColumn(Input, "total", each null, type number))) in result, type table}} ),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Running_Total, "Data", {"Date", "Sales", "total"}, {"Date", "Sales", "total"})
in #"Expanded Data"
```

I cannot take credit for method 2, borrowed long ago, but do not recall source

Comment: Thank you, I've got "Function" in each cell of the table, please see my edited question above for more details.

Comment: I just retried code above. Seems fine. Please post yours

Comment: = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Personalizado", each (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Index]<=i[Index]) [Sales]))

Comment: Sorry. I meant please post the whole block of code

Comment: Stack overflow doens't let me paste the whole code here, I'll just update my question above, thank you

Comment: I updated my answer on the bottom with pasted code

Comment: I'm trying to use the code you provided, but it is "evaluating..." for hours

Comment: are you using the table.buffer() around the index? Table.Buffer(Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1)),

Comment: Yes, I'm using exactly the first chunk of code in your post - except for the source of course. And it is taking hours just to evaluate.

Comment: Maybe, it just runs forever, even in a Premium capacity. It is impossible to calculate this in Power BI. I'll try it in R, maybe it's faster. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I finally made it! Using a premium capacity data flow! Thank you! I'll open another question to calculate the sales of the last 365 days with Power Query, it shouldn't be too difficult now..